# is it allowed to save meta data about youtube videos in local databases

Tags: youtube-api

Is it allowed to save meta-data like video lengths, keywords and specific event information at certain point in time in the video?

For example, there is a movie trailer and I want to save the point in the video where a certain event occurs in my own database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the information is being used in conjunction with the YouTube api/player, then there is no problem as you are just creating shortcuts to an evet.

If you are not sure, then you can read the [YouTube terms of service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/api-services-terms-of-service) for an in depth answer.

Comment: I am trying to embed youtube videos in my own app. I am going to use my own player/skin but of course i am going to retain youtube branding.

Comment: How you skin the player makes no difference, unless you intend to hide the link to YouTube. As you are not hiding it, then answer still stands. You should have no problem from what I can see..